# Repeated errors despite correct namespace

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors, ns-3

I added a class to `ns3` and when using it I keep getting the error:

```
../scratch/seven.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../scratch/seven.cc:102:3: error: ‘RandomAppHelper’ was not declared in this scope
   RandomAppHelper source = RandomAppHelper ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address ("192.168.1.10"), 10));
   ^
../scratch/seven.cc:103:3: error: ‘source’ was not declared in this scope
   source.SetAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("Constant:2.5"));
   ^
```

The code for this is here: https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.3/doxygen/application.html

I can't resolve the error. I used the correct `namespace` `ns3` in the code. Since the error is of "not declared in scope", I am not sure how to rectify it.

Here is my implementation of the helper class (which I am using):

```
#include "ns3/log.h"
#include "ns3/address.h"
#include "ns3/node.h"
#include "ns3/nstime.h"
#include "ns3/socket.h"
#include "ns3/simulator.h"
#include "ns3/socket-factory.h"
#include "ns3/packet.h"
#include "ns3/uinteger.h"
#include "ns3/trace-source-accessor.h"
#include "ns3/tcp-socket-factory.h"
#include "random-helper.h"

namespace ns3{

RandomAppHelper::RandomAppHelper (std::string protocol, Address remote)
{
  m_factory.SetTypeId ("ns3::MpTcpBulkSendApplication");
  m_factory.Set ("Protocol", StringValue (protocol));
  m_factory.Set ("Remote", AddressValue (remote));
}

void
RandomAppHelper::SetAttribute (std::string name, const AttributeValue &value)
{
  m_factory.Set (name, value);
}

ApplicationContainer
RandomAppHelper::Install (Ptr<Node> node) const
{
  return ApplicationContainer (InstallPriv (node));
}

ApplicationContainer
RandomAppHelper::Install (std::string nodeName) const
{
  Ptr<Node> node = Names::Find<Node> (nodeName);
  return ApplicationContainer (InstallPriv (node));
}

ApplicationContainer
RandomAppHelper::Install (NodeContainer c) const
{
  ApplicationContainer apps;
  for (NodeContainer::Iterator i = c.Begin (); i != c.End (); ++i)
    {
      apps.Add (InstallPriv (*i));
    }

  return apps;
}

Ptr<Application>
RandomAppHelper::InstallPriv (Ptr<Node> node) const
{
  Ptr<Application> app = m_factory.Create<Application> ();
  node->AddApplication (app);

  return app;
}


}
```

This class is defined in the applications folder of ns3, which is included via the **applications-module.h include.**  And in my code I have included it at the place where I use the RandomAppHelper.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a standard ns3 class, but rather a helper-class you have to define and implement yourself.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation. Porque downvote?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course, I defined and implmented it myself.

Comment: And *where* did you define it? You do include the header file where the class is defined? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us (in the body of the question).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Added the details. Sorry for the clumsiness earlier.

Comment: Hi, the link you provided for applications is outdated. Please use the documentation for the ns-3 release that your are using. Second, when you added this helper class, did you modify the wscript file of the applications module? After that re-configure ns-3 (./waf configure) in order to 'see' the modifications.

Comment: @Konstantinos hi, are there tutorials for the newer versions of ns3 that create traffic generators ? or any library for traffic generation or topology creations also ?

Comment: There is a topology generator tool recently updated to ns-3.25 (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ns-3-users/aJzkLUtXOx8/2vtpQRCVEgAJ)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add your file names(I guess you created RandomAppHelper) in the wscript.py file located in the application folder. 
Hope it works.
Bye